# What is taking up 320 seconds on my bootup?

Tags: boot, dmesg

Hi I've run a dmesg after booting with a kernel with loglevel=7.

```
[   19.439254] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88080e62f248
[   19.439255] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88080e62f200
[   19.439256] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88080e62f290
[   19.439257] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88080e62f2d8
[   19.439258] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88080e62f320
[   19.439671] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5392, rev 0223 detected
[   19.449271] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5372 detected
[   19.451573] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[   19.451773] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb
[  340.533178] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Broken pipe
[  340.534894] init: failsafe main process (844) killed by TERM signal
[  341.270880] audit: type=1400 audit(1418215536.094:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=993 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  341.270884] audit: type=1400 audit(1418215536.094:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="chromium" pid=993 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  341.272056] audit: type=1400 audit(1418215536.098:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lightdm-remote-session-freerdp/freerdp-session-wrapper" pid=993 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  341.272059] audit: type=1400 audit(1418215536.098:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="chromium" pid=993 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  341.273154] audit: type=1400 audit(1418215536.098:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure/uccsconfigure-session-wrapper" pid=993 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  341.273157] audit: type=1400 audit(1418215536.098:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="chromium" pid=993 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  341.273922] audit: type=1400 audit(1418215536.098:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=993 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  341.273926] audit: type=1400 audit(1418215536.098:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=993 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  341.273928] audit: type=1400 audit(1418215536.098:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=993 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

What is taking 320 seconds? How can I debug this?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Here is my `sudo lshw -class network`

```
 *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 06
   serial: 74:d4:35:1a:fb:8b
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits                                                                                                                                                                     
   clock: 33MHz                                                                                                                                                                       
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation                                 
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s                                                                                                                                                                                 
   resources: irq:44 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f3104000-f3104fff memory:f3100000-f3103fff                                                                                          


*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:9
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: c8:3a:35:cc:12:44
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.16.0-28-generic firmware=0.29 ip=10.0.0.5 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

**uname -r**
`3.16.0-28-generic`

**lsb_release --codename**
`Codename:       utopic`

Comment: mine says: `[   11.116748] init: samba-ad-dc main process (746) terminated with status 1
[   11.380492] init: failsafe main process (727) killed by TERM signal` so it must be a mistake in the `rt2800usb` wireless package.  Can you do a `lshw -class network` and then [edit] your question and add the output to it?

Comment: Could you give me your `uname -r` and `lsb_release --codename`?

Comment: @Fabby I've added the output of the two commands.

Comment: Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1364630 "In my experience this bug will occur in Utopic (not in Trusty) upstart network initializaton, if DHCP is set ( not static )
It has nothing to do with the display drivers."

Comment: @Rinzwind I've tried without the Nvidia drivers also to no avail.

Comment: You did not read the bug report? (or just the title?) See #55 and onwards.

Comment: Yes I have read the bug report. But that is not strictly related to long boot times. Especially not as extreme as in my case. Also this happened before Utopic on the same machine.

Comment: I'd just try blacklisting rt2800usb. I had system locks using this driver with kernel 3.16

Comment: Climax: @Rinzwind is better then me (I've got only 1 gold medal: he's got 10 or so) If he says it's this bug, I believe him. OK, seems like you are affected.  Answering now...

Comment: @Fabby gold medals have nothing to do with this. Climax: I know. The notice is the same so tracking the problem will take the same effort. That notice is a bit vague (init is big and a more specific notice would help...). davidbaumann might be correct too. The notice in front of it "19.451773] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb" *should* be related. Disable it and try again.

Comment: @davidbaumann: could you take up your side of this and if your hunch is better then mine, downvote my answer and I'll delete it.

Comment: It's just a test... I guess he needs the device :)

Comment: Removing the device and blacklisting didn't fix the problem. Still above 320s boot times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1364630) which is incorrectly named "nvidia drivers" but is actually an Intel network driver bug.

Best to subscribe to the bug list and open a new question once the bug gets resolved.

In the mean time: you'll have to live with long boot times.

**Workaround:** use "hibernate" as much as possible in the mean time.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it is probably the closest to the real reason. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that! :-) I'm sorry to have not been of much help ("help"="solving it") but at least you know what the problem is (and knowing what the problem is, is 80% of the solution!)  ;-)