# Safely remove for removeable hard drive doesn't work

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive, external-hdd, eject

Safely removing my portable WD Elements USB 3.0 1TB drive doesn't actually safely remove it. I get no notification that it is in fact safe to remove even when having done nothing on the disk.

It does unmount when safely removing, but when I do copy files it still unmounts but there is still full on disk activity.

Also when copying files the file dialog in nautilus closes before the actual files have finished copying (I guess it is due to the file cache still syncing).

So safely removing my disk is pointless and time and time again I get to another computer and my copied files are missing or corrupt/incomplete.

Also this happens with standard USB 2 flash disks as well, and with other external hard disks.

This didn't happen in 14.04, only since 14.10.

Edit: flash disks use FAT32 and external drives use NTFS

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please tell us what file system you are using?

Comment: @Fabby I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution to the problem, but a work-around until this problem gets resolved in 14.10 (14.04.1 doesn't have this problem, read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) why.)

1. Do a `chkdsk /f` under Windows of all affected drives first (to bring them into a consistent state)!
2. Before unplugging the devices use the following method:

   a. close all file manager windows.

   b. open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

   c. type the `sync` command and wait until the prompt returns

   d. *only now* right-click the device, and select <kbd>Eject</kbd>.  If eject is not available, select <kbd>Unmount</kbd>

   e. unplug the device before doing anything else

Comment: Thanks @Fabby. A workaround for the moment is all I need!

Comment: That's the second problem I've solved for you!  Ek gaan jou geld hef!  ;-)

Comment: dankie vir al die hulp. Ken ek jou? Of hoe het jy geweet ek is Afrikaans?

Comment: :D :D :D craftycode.co.za in jou profiel???  En dit is gewoon die tweede probleem wat ek opgelos heb vir jou: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/558818/what-is-taking-up-320-seconds-on-my-bootup) en ik praat baaie sleg Afrikaans...  ;-)

Comment: So a fellow South African? Or expat?

Comment: Worse! A tourist!  ;-)  Been there in 1992 on a holiday to: Warmbad, wine route, Kaapstad, JoBurg, Drakensbergen and back again and again in 2004 to JoBurg for work...  You live in the most beautiful country in the world!  **;-)**